# Buttons text not changing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the text of a button to that of a value stored in a variable. The button is currently blank and not even using a fixed value like `.value = "test";` is working.

HTML:

```
<div id="addContainer">
    <textarea id="listTitleInput" class="textarea" placeholder="Add the title of your list here, then click 'Add List'." rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
    <button id="addListBtn" data-role="button">Add List</button>
</div>

<div id="listDisplayContainer">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//LISTS
    var listTitleInput = document.getElementById("listTitleInput");
    var addListBtn = document.getElementById("addListBtn");
    var listCount = localStorage.getItem("listCount"); 

if (listCount === null) {
        noteCount = 0;
    }

//ADD LISTS
    function addList() {
        if ($("#listTitleInput").val() == "") {
            alert("Please give your list a title, then click 'Add List'.");
        } else {
            listCount++;
            var list = $("#listTitleInput").val();
            console.log("List Count: " + listCount);
            console.log(list);
            var display = document.createElement("button");
            document.getElementById("listDisplayContainer").appendChild(display);
            display.className = "ui-btn";
            display.id = "list" + listCount;
            $("#list" + listCount).value = list;

        }
    }

//Lists
    addListBtn.addEventListener("click", addList);

});
```

Comment: `<button>` elements don't have a "value" property. You have to change the `.innerHTML` to change the content.

Comment: Also I get confused a little when I see a mix of jQuery and native DOM code. Why not stick with one or the other?

Comment: Unfortunatley $("#list" + listCount).innerHTML = list; isn't working either

Comment: Thats because `innerHTML` is a native DOM atrtribute. You need to use `.html()`

Comment: This kind of thing is why mixing DOM stuff and jQuery stuff always makes my head spin. Go with one or the other until you're really comfortable with the relationship.

Comment: You can't just mix DOM objects and jQuery objects like that. You would need to use `$("#list" + listCount)[0].innerHTML = list;`. Instead do `$("#list" + listCount).html(list);`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to get used more to using jQuery solely. Is it just the getElementByID stuff or is there more DOM code which I shouldn't be using? Sometimes I'm not actually sure which belongs to which as I began using jQuery almost immediatley

Comment: `.getElementById()`, `.createElement()`, `.appendChild()`, getting/setting the "class", all that can be done with jQuery APIs. It's not that one is better than the other, it's that mixing the two is confusing if you're not really secure in what the difference is.

Comment: @Pointy thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are confusing native DOM attributes with jQuery ones.

`$("#list" + listCount).value = list;`

`$("#list" + listCount)` is a jQuery object so it doesn't use the native javascript properties that you may be used to. (`value=`)

What you are looking for is:

`$("#list" + listCount).html(list);`

Or

`$("#list" + listCount).text(list);`

Since `list` is a string value, it will be best to use `.text`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to change `$("#list" + listCount).value = list;` to `$("#list" + listCount).text(list);`

value is not a property and val() doesn't work for a button.